# CORE DATA objectId changes constantly

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have some data that I export into an XML file and put in a remote FTP Server.

I have to identified each object with a unique attribute, it doesn't matter wich is, but must be persistent always => it can never change.

I don't want to create a unique attribute, sequence, serial, etc.

I'm using the objectID but every time I use it a get a new reference.

I know that before the object has been saved, it has a 'temporal id', but once it's saved, it gets the definitive.

I'm not seeing this, never.

When I export, just fetch all data and loop, and always I get a new reference:

```
NSURL *objectID = [[personalDataObject objectID] URIRepresentation];

// some of id received for the SAME OBJECT (no changes made, saved, ...)
// 61993296
// 62194624
```

thanks,

r.

### edit

I was using %d instead of %@, now the returned data is:

```
x-coredata://F46F3300-8FED-4876-B0BF-E4D2A9D80913/DataEntered/p1
x-coredata://F46F3300-8FED-4876-B0BF-E4D2A9D80913/DataEntered/p2
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create a unique id? I'd always take that option given the choice!

Comment: I don't want to have an entity/table just to store and increment a counter there ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this maybe a reporting problem. The numbers you show that are supposed to be a URI/UUID are way, way to short.

[They should look like](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html):

> UUIDs (Universally Unique
>   Identifiers), also known as GUIDs
>   (Globally Unique Identifiers) or IIDs
>   (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit
>   values guaranteed to be unique. A UUID
>   is made unique over both space and
>   time by combining a value unique to
>   the computer on which it was
>   generated—usually the Ethernet
>   hardware address—and a value
>   representing the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals since October
>   15, 1582 at 00:00:00.
>
> The standard format for UUIDs
>   represented in ASCII is a string
>   punctuated by hyphens, for example
>   68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067.
>   The hex representation looks, as you
>   might expect, like a list of numerical
>   values preceded by 0x. For example,
>   0xD7, 0x36, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x4D, 0x6E,
>   0x12, 0x26, 0x80, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x50,
>   0xE4, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x67 . To use a
>   UUID, you simply create it and then
>   copy the resulting strings into your
>   header and C language source files.
>   Because a UUID is expressed simply as
>   an array of bytes, there are no
>   endianness considerations for
>   different platforms.

I think you're seeing different values because your only getting a piece, and a different piece at that, each time you check the UUID. Represented as a URI, they should look more like a URL. They definitely won't look like an integer.

Comment: ok, maybe the problem is when I take the value of the URIRepresentation, I'm going to check again and post again! thanks

Comment: @mongeta: Are you using `%d` instead of `%@` in your `NSLog` function?  If so, then you'll see the memory address of the URL, rather than the string representation.

Answer (score 19):

The `NSManagedObjectID` is not guaranteed to be consistent.  It can change based on a number of factors including data migration and other factors.  If you are using this as a unique identifier for your objects, stop.

The only time you want to use the `NSManagedObjectID` is when you need to pass references between threads.  Other than that situation you should not rely upon it for anything.

If you need a unique id then create one and store it in your entities.