# ios: why NSManagedObjectID object cannot be weak reference?

Tags: ios, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I have a weak property:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSManagedObjectID *locatedMessageID;
```

App will crash when calling `-(void)setLocatedMessageId`. The error is:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP).

To solve this problem, only replace 'weak' keyword to 'assign'.

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSManagedObjectID *locatedMessageID;
```

But is it safe? Why I cannot use weak property here?

Comment: Why do you store `NSManagedObjectID` in a property? It may not work as you expect, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2821001/2128900

Comment: Is the property explicitly `synthesized`?

Comment: I add this code '@synthesize locatedMessageID = _locatedMessageID;
', got the same error.

Answer (score -1):

`NSManagedObjectID` is not advisable. Use the object itself instead. You have convenient access to all associated objects and attributes - there is really no need to explicitly fetch the object again based on the object ID.

Contrary to the comment below, you are better off with the object itself.

Comment: Actually, do the opposite. A managed object is a collection of references to things in the context, identified by the managed object id - this is why using the object ID is often preferable to using the managed object.